# Is there any way to change CMake toolchain without setting up environment variables?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, toolchain

I'm just curious to know if there is a way to set up the CMake toolchain without using environment variables at all.
I like to directly call the CMake program defining the full path to `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`, `CMAKE_CXX COMPILER`, and `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` without anything to do with the environment variables Is it possible?
If this isn't possible then is there any way to tell CMake where to look up for further dependency if it needs or if we can provide CMake some other files to set up everything for use instead of manually setting environment variables?
Best regards.

Comment: `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path`

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want to set without using environment variables? That could improve the googlability of your post for people with similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can set [toolchain variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) in a small cmake file. Then use a toolchain [file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling) with cmake call

```
cmake --toolchain path/to/toolchain-file.cmake <other-options>
```

That's equivalent of

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/toolchain-file.cmake <other-options>
```

Comment: I prefer using [`--toolchain path/to/toolchain-file.cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-toolchain) since this way cmake will prevent incorrect use like typos in the variable name or attempting to change the toolchain file after the initial configuration...

Comment: @NimaGhorab Ask a new question. Don't edit the original question. You make it unrelated to the given answer.